# In Boost serialization,boost_shared pointer does not compile.. give error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, serialization, boost

I'm trying to serialize shared pointer using boost but it gives error :
**Error 1   error C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type c:\users\allwork\hope\lib\boost_1_55_0\boost\mpl\print.hpp   51  1   Input**

I even tried the solution given at link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409755/boost-serialization-fails-gives-compile-time-error-c4308 
but still issue exists.

If i comment line - **" ar & MyStruct; "** error goes off. Please let me know where mistake or issue is exist with respect to current code.

Below is the code :

// MyStruct.hpp file

```
struct MyStruct
{
std::string rollno;
std::string address;
***boost::shared_ptr<MyStruct> Mydata;*** 

private:
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template
void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
{
ar & rollno;
ar & address;
ar & Mydata; 
} 

public:
MyStruct(void);
MyStruct(const parameter_strings & parms);

virtual ~MyStruct(void);
};
}

// MyStruct.cpp file

MyStruct::MyStruct(void)
{
}

MyStruct::~MyStruct(void)
{
}

MyStruct::MyStruct(const parameter_strings & parms)
{
// implementation 
}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(MyStruct);   BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(MyStruct,boost::serialization::object_serializable);
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(MyStruct,boost::serialization::track_selectively);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

Comment: even after adding above header files.. issue still exists